# Node.js passport.use() function: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm following a tutorial on using Node.js and passport for a login system (here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RCnNyD0L-s)

I have downloaded/updated all the libraries many times over so I don't think the passport library is the issue. I've also checked all the variables and they're correct. I think the error is to-do with the authenticateUser being undefined, which is weird because authenticateUser is asynchronous.
I've required express, passport and other libraries on another files which also requires this one.
Here's the code:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

function initialize(__passport, getUserByUsername) {
    const authenticateUser = async (username, password, done) => {
        const user = getUserByUsername(username)
        if (await user==null) {
            return done(null, false, {message: "No user with that username found"})
        }

        try {
            if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, user)
            } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: "Incorrect password"})
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return done(e)
        }
    }  
    console.log("USEEERRR: " +   authenticateUser) 
    __passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'username'}, authenticateUser))
    __passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {})
    __passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {})
}

module.exports = initialize()
```

This is the error that I'm getting in Terminal:

```
USEEERRR: async (username, password, done) => {
        const user = getUserByUsername(username)
        if (await user==null) {
            return done(null, false, {message: "No user with that username found"})
        }

        try {
            if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, user)
            } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: "Incorrect password"})
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return done(e)
        }
    }
/Users/alessandra/Desktop/CS IA/NODE-LOGIN-SIGNUP/passport-config.js:22
    __passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'username'}, authenticateUser))
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
    at initialize (/Users/alessandra/Desktop/CS IA/NODE-LOGIN-SIGNUP/passport-config.js:22:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alessandra/Desktop/CS IA/NODE-LOGIN-SIGNUP/passport-config.js:27:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alessandra/Desktop/CS IA/NODE-LOGIN-SIGNUP/server.js:19:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Can you include the other file

Comment: Did you mean `module.exports = initialize`? `initialize` doesn’t return anything; `initialize` expects two arguments, but you pass zero.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem... Sorry... I'm new to node.js and Javascript in general!